# How to append multiple lists to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

Suppose I have three lists:

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = ['a','b','c']
list_c = [4,5,6]
```

How do I create a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {1:{'a':4},2:{'b':5},3:{'c':6}
```

I was thinking of using the defaultdict command from the collections module or creating a class but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can utilize `zip` and dictionary comprehension to solve this:

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = ['a','b','c']
list_c = [4,5,6]
final_dict = {a:{b:c} for a, b, c in zip(list_a, list_b, list_c)}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'a': 4}, 2: {'b': 5}, 3: {'c': 6}}
```